# How do I cast ViewModifier Content to anticipated type?

Tags: swiftui

So I think I could be using `ViewModifiers` incorrectly, but is it possible to cast the `Content` of a `ViewModifier` to the anticipated type, e.g. `Text`? I want to use `.fontWeight(.bold)` but that is not part of the base/aliastype `Content`. Alternatively what should I use to achieve this effect? A custom `Style` function?

```
struct ButtonTextModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        (content as Text) //<--- ERROR HERE
            .fontWeight(.bold) //<--- Because I want to use this
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .padding()
    }
}
```

The error I get:

`Cannot convert value of type 'ButtonTextModifier.Content' (aka '_ViewModifier_Content<ButtonTextModifier>') to type 'Text' in coercion`

Answer (score 1):

You might have to add a new method on `Text` by declaring it in it's extension.

```
extension Text {
    func buttonTextModifier() -> some View {
        self
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .padding()
    }
}
```